# Trying to access an element of an embedded array

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures

This is a large data structure with many embedded arrays. Each array has n elements, in this example, 37. I am trying to access the 'content' element in the 1st and 3rd position, of each of the arrays.

array[1]->percentage->content

and

array[3]->grade->content

$tdata is the variable that contains the data structure. I have tried looping over like this:

```
$i=0;
  foreach($tdata as $td){

    if($td[$i] == 1 OR $td[$i] == 3){
     var_dump($td[$i])
    }

   $i++;
 }
```

This is the data structure.

```
array (size=37)

0 => 
 array (size=2)
  'leader' => 
    array (size=2)
       'class' => string '...' (length=18)
       'rowspan' => int 37
   'itemname' => 
     array (size=2)
       'colspan' => int 6
       'content' => string '...' (length=159)
1 => 
  array (size=2)
    'grade' => 
      array (size=2)
        'class' => string '...' (length=25)
        'content' => string '43.37 %' (length=7)
    'percentage' => 
      array (size=2)
        'class' => string '  oddd1 baggb itemcenter ' (length=25)
        'content' => string '43.37 %' (length=7)
2 => 
  array (size=1)
    'leader' => 
      array (size=2)
       'class' => string ' oddd2 b1t b2b b1l' (length=18)
       'rowspan' => int 32
3 => 
  array (size=1)
    'grade' => 
      array (size=2)
        'class' => string '  oddd2 baggb itemcenter ' (length=25)
        'content' => string '6.30 %' (length=6)
  .
  .
  .

array (size=37)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'leader' => 
        array (size=2)
          'class' => string '...' (length=18)
          'rowspan' => int 37
      'itemname' => 
        array (size=2)
          'colspan' => int 6
          'content' => string '...' (length=159)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'grade' => 
        array (size=2)
          'class' => string '...' (length=25)
          'content' => string '26.49 %' (length=7)
      'percentage' => 
        array (size=2)
          'class' => string '  oddd1 baggb itemcenter ' (length=25)
          'content' => string '26.49 %' (length=7)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'leader' => 
        array (size=2)
          'class' => string ' oddd2 b1t b2b b1l' (length=18)
          'rowspan' => int 32
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'grade' => 
    array (size=2)
    'class' => string '  oddd2 baggb itemcenter ' (length=25)
    'content' => string '11.12 %' (length=6)
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: So your question is how to determine when the key is 1 or 3 or..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($tdata as $i => $td)
{
    if($i == 1 || $i == 3)
    {
        var_dump($td[$i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($tdata as $key => $data ){    
    if( $key === 1 || $key === 3){
     var_dump( $data ); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;
  foreach($tdata as $td){

    if($i == 0 || $i == 2){
     var_dump($td[$i])
    }

   $i++;
 }
```